# Proof that a subset $W$ in $A$ is closed in $\tau_A$ if and only if there exists $F$ closed in $(X,\tau)$ such that $W=A\cap F$.

Tags: general-topology

Note: $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, $A$ is a non-empty subset of $A$, $\mathcal{T}_A=\{A\cap U: U\in \mathcal{T}\}$.

> Assume that $W\subseteq A$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_A$. Then $A\backslash W$ is open, i.e. there exists $U$ open in $X$ such that $A\backslash W= A\cap U$.
>
> The last equality may be re-written as $W=A\backslash A\cap U=A\backslash U=A\cap(X\backslash U)$. The set $F=X\backslash U$ is closed in $X$.

How do we know that $X\backslash U$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: Because $U$ is open. What definition of ‘closed’ do you have?

Comment: That its complement is open. Oh yes, it's obvious.